# Conocer los requisitos de APP

Tags: android, ionic, app

Tengo una APP (hecha en Ionic) de la cual me piden aportar algunos datos (por motivos de clausulas, etc...), entre los cuales se encuentran:

- Requerimientos mínimos del dispositivo.
- RAM necesaria para que funcione.

Y la verdad es que no tengo ni idea de a dónde ir o a qué recurrir para conocerlos.

Teneís alguna idea? Existe alguna herramienta que te permita conocer estos datos? o aunque sea dar un valor aproximado al menos..

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Donde se pide aportar esos datos?

Comment: @Jorgesys es por un tema de contratos, clausulas y demás cosas de la empresa. El caso es que no tengo ni idea de cómo poder conocer esos datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu app es Android te sugiero lo siguiente para tus preguntas:

1. > Requerimientos mínimos del dispositivo.

Para ionic puedes determinar que versión minima es requerida dentro de tu archivo `config.xml` mediante :

en este ejemplo la versión minima que soporta tu aplicación sería Android 4.4 (API nivel 19)

Similar a como se define en Android Studio dentro del archivo `build.gradle` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. > RAM necesaria para que funcione.

Para tener un estimado de cuanta memoria podría llegar a utilizar tu app, puedes usar el
[Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?hl=es-419) para esto [tendrías que hacer uso de Android Studio](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android)

[Cómo medir el rendimiento de las apps con Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?hl=es-419)

De esta forma podrías obtener un estimado de uso de memoría por parte de tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]